# rhino licensing problem

Tags: javascript, licensing, rhino

Hi I have not well understand how rhino license works.

I would like make a commercial application (desktop) and embedding rhino to make available javascript to my users for easy customizing the application.

according license there's seems there's no probs I only should print in copyright rhino notice..

http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/download.html

but reading better I'm seeing that rhino is under MPL/GPL license

so how can I do?
if rhino is impossible to add there's an other script language like python, boo etc. to safe embededd into NET/Mono application?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it a little weird to embed Rhino in a .NET application?  I mean, it's implemented in Java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick glance at the Mozilla site it seems that Mozilla libraries and software have dual, even tri-licenses. This means that you can pick the most appropriate license when using the software or library. This is often done as some software licenses can cause problems when they are combined, therefore developers sometime release software under alternative licensing.

With MPL you're good to go in including Rhino in a commercial program. From Wikipedia:

*"Unlike strong copyleft licenses, the code under the MPL may be combined with proprietary files in one program ("Larger Work")."*

Comment: Which makes you wonder why it was released under GPL at all. Is there something in the MPL which stops it being used in GPL projects?

Comment: @Tom Anderson: I'm guessing the MPL might conflict with GPL to some extent as MPL can be used in proprietary software.

Comment: @TuomasR: It seems you're right about MPL conflicting with GPL, although it's not to do with being able to be used in proprietary software (eg 2-clause BSD can be used in proprietary software, but is compatible with the GPL). There is some information at http://www.tomhull.com/ocston/docs/mozgpl.html and http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLIncompatibleLicenses

Comment: @Pointy no, according this  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EmbeddingJSCS.aspx

Comment: I've wrote to firefox support and this is the answer "Neither licence prohibits commercial use (prohibiting commercial use is not allowed in any open source licence), but you need to follow the terms of the licence. If you don't understand them, it's probably best to consult a lawyer. They are supposed to be fairly easy to understand, but we can't offer legal advice.
" so you right :)